# How to add Bazel BUILD rules for open telemetry protos?

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules

I am trying to add BUILD rules for Open telemetry logs and metrics [protos](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-proto/tree/main/opentelemetry/proto).
I am not too familiar with Bazel, hence struggling to figure out how to add relevant http_archive() and load dependencies for the same.

Tried adding following to the WORKSPACE but could not succeed.

```
http_archive(
    name = "com_opentelemetry_proto",
    sha256 = "a13a1a7b76a1f22a0ca2e6c293e176ffef031413ab8ba653a82a1dbc286a3a33",
    strip_prefix = "opentelemetry-proto-1.0.0",
    urls = ["https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-proto/archive/v1.0.0.tar.gz"],
)
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Whats the problem you are facing. ? like error logs ?